# bulk sms on Lumia 920

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, sms, amber-update

Since I updated my Lumia 920 to Lumia Amber, I discovered that sending SMS to multiple contacts has become impossible. Noticed that immediately after it was updated, my network carrier says it is a phone setting that has caused that. Can anyone help or have the same issues?

Comment: Who is your carrier?

Comment: I can confirm that this feature works on Lumia 928 Verizon, Lumia 920 ATT, and Lumia 520 Tmobile. All US carriers, all on Amber.

Comment: Well..., my carrier is Airtel but I can confirm that the feature was working until my Lumia 920 was upgraded to Amber. Personally, I know that it was the upgrade that affected something on my 920.

Comment: By network carrier, I mean my wireless network operator. My Lumia 920 is not branded by them as caschw has put it.

Comment: You should get in touch with the folks at Airtel. They would be your best bet of finding out why you can't send group text anymore.

Comment: My 920 is not branded, and I still can send sms to many people at once.

Comment: As I said, I could send an SMS to multiple contacts at once before the Lumia Amber upgrade. Been to Airtel and my line was tested with another phone and it could send SMS to multiple contacts at once. They advised that a Nokia care center should solve the problem as they believe it is a software issue.

Comment: What exactly happens when you compose an SMS, add multiple recipients and try to send? what error do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Messaging settings, at the bottom there is an option:

```
Group text (on/off)
Keeps replies in one thread using MMS.
```

Is this option turned on? If it is, then the reason your group SMSes are failing is probably because your phone doesn't have MMS settings for your carrier.

Either turn this option off, or try going to **Settings app > access point** to configure MMS settings for your carrier.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Jingtao that solved the problem. I can now send my SMS to multiple contacts at a go. Really grateful for that.

Comment: @Akyemfak not a problem. You may still want to configure your MMS settings as mentioned above so you can also send MMSes (picture messages). Also could you mark this as the correct answer please? :)

Comment: how do I mark that as the correct answer?

Comment: @Akyemfak http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers